# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 256

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement seq2seq model for text summarization using Tensorflow 1.3.0.

I am trying to use `MultiRNNCell` and `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` in encoding layer. I am missing something, but unable to find it. The error stack trace is not straight forward which makes it more difficult to understand.

I am getting below error while building the Graph.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    653           graph_def_version, node_def_str, input_shapes, input_tensors,
--> 654           input_tensors_as_shapes, status)
    655   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as err:

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 256 for 'decoding/decoder/while/BasicDecoderStep/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,512], [?,256].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-85ee67bc88e5> in <module>()
      9     # Create the training and inference logits
     10     training_logits, inference_logits = seq2seq_model(input_,target,embeding_matrix,vocab_to_int,source_seq_length,target_seq_length,
---> 11                   max_target_seq_length,rnn_size,keep_probability,num_layers,batch_size)
     12 
     13     # Create tensors for the training logits and inference logits

<ipython-input-114-5ad1bf459bd7> in seq2seq_model(source_input, target_input, embeding_matrix, vocab_to_int, source_sequence_length, target_sequence_length, max_target_length, rnn_size, keep_prob, num_layers, batch_size)
     15     training_logits, inference_logits = decoding_layer(target_input,encoder_states,embedings,
     16                                                                 vocab_to_int,rnn_size,target_sequence_length,
---> 17                                                                 max_target_length,batch_size,num_layers)
     18 
     19     return training_logits, inference_logits

<ipython-input-113-c2b4542605d2> in decoding_layer(target_inputs, encoder_state, embedding, vocab_to_int, rnn_size, target_sequence_length, max_target_length, batch_size, num_layers)
     12 
     13         training_logits = training_decoder(embed,decoder_cell,encoder_state,output_layer,
---> 14                                          target_sequence_length,max_target_length)
     15 
     16 

<ipython-input-117-012bbcdcf997> in training_decoder(dec_embed_input, decoder_cell, encoder_state, output_layer, target_sequence_length, max_target_length)
     17 
     18     final_outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder=decoder,impute_finished=True,
---> 19                                                      maximum_iterations=max_target_length)
     20 
     21     return final_outputs

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/decoder.py in dynamic_decode(decoder, output_time_major, impute_finished, maximum_iterations, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, scope)
    284         ],
    285         parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
--> 286         swap_memory=swap_memory)
    287 
    288     final_outputs_ta = res[1]

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
   2773     context = WhileContext(parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
   2774     ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.WHILE_CONTEXT, context)
-> 2775     result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2776     return result
   2777 

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in BuildLoop(self, pred, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2602       self.Enter()
   2603       original_body_result, exit_vars = self._BuildLoop(
-> 2604           pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2605     finally:
   2606       self.Exit()

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in _BuildLoop(self, pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2552         structure=original_loop_vars,
   2553         flat_sequence=vars_for_body_with_tensor_arrays)
-> 2554     body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
   2555     if not nest.is_sequence(body_result):
   2556       body_result = [body_result]

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/decoder.py in body(time, outputs_ta, state, inputs, finished, sequence_lengths)
    232       """
    233       (next_outputs, decoder_state, next_inputs,
--> 234        decoder_finished) = decoder.step(time, inputs, state)
    235       next_finished = math_ops.logical_or(decoder_finished, finished)
    236       if maximum_iterations is not None:

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/basic_decoder.py in step(self, time, inputs, state, name)
    137     """
    138     with ops.name_scope(name, "BasicDecoderStep", (time, inputs, state)):
--> 139       cell_outputs, cell_state = self._cell(inputs, state)
    140       if self._output_layer is not None:
    141         cell_outputs = self._output_layer(cell_outputs)

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    178       with vs.variable_scope(vs.get_variable_scope(),
    179                              custom_getter=self._rnn_get_variable):
--> 180         return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
    181 
    182   def _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs):

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    448         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    449         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
--> 450         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    451 
    452         # Apply activity regularization.

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in call(self, inputs, state)
    936                                       [-1, cell.state_size])
    937           cur_state_pos += cell.state_size
--> 938         cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
    939         new_states.append(new_state)
    940 

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    772                              self._recurrent_input_noise,
    773                              self._input_keep_prob)
--> 774     output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope)
    775     if _should_dropout(self._state_keep_prob):
    776       new_state = self._dropout(new_state, "state",

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    178       with vs.variable_scope(vs.get_variable_scope(),
    179                              custom_getter=self._rnn_get_variable):
--> 180         return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
    181 
    182   def _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs):

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    448         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    449         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
--> 450         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    451 
    452         # Apply activity regularization.

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in call(self, inputs, state)
    405 
    406     new_c = (
--> 407         c * sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * self._activation(j))
    408     new_h = self._activation(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
    409 

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    863           else:
    864             raise
--> 865       return func(x, y, name=name)
    866 
    867   def binary_op_wrapper_sparse(sp_x, y):

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py in _mul_dispatch(x, y, name)
   1086   is_tensor_y = isinstance(y, ops.Tensor)
   1087   if is_tensor_y:
-> 1088     return gen_math_ops._mul(x, y, name=name)
   1089   else:
   1090     assert isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor)  # Case: Dense * Sparse.

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in _mul(x, y, name)
   1447     A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `x`.
   1448   """
-> 1449   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
   1450   return result
   1451 

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    765         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, output_types, name=scope,
    766                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 767                          op_def=op_def)
    768         if output_structure:
    769           outputs = op.outputs

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in create_op(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_shapes, compute_device)
   2630                     original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
   2631     if compute_shapes:
-> 2632       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
   2633     self._add_op(ret)
   2634     self._record_op_seen_by_control_dependencies(ret)

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shapes_for_outputs(op)
   1909       shape_func = _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op
   1910 
-> 1911   shapes = shape_func(op)
   1912   if shapes is None:
   1913     raise RuntimeError(

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in call_with_requiring(op)
   1859 
   1860   def call_with_requiring(op):
-> 1861     return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
   1862 
   1863   _call_cpp_shape_fn_and_require_op = call_with_requiring

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn)
    593     res = _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed,
    594                                   input_tensors_as_shapes_needed,
--> 595                                   require_shape_fn)
    596     if not isinstance(res, dict):
    597       # Handles the case where _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl calls unknown_shape(op).

~/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl(op, input_tensors_needed, input_tensors_as_shapes_needed, require_shape_fn)
    657       missing_shape_fn = True
    658     else:
--> 659       raise ValueError(err.message)
    660 
    661   if missing_shape_fn:

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 256 for 'decoding/decoder/while/BasicDecoderStep/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,512], [?,256].
```

I am not able to understand the error. Which matrix is it trying to refer? Please help me, I am fairly new to Tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that inside the LSTM of the decoder (`decoding/decoder/while/BasicDecoderStep/decoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/mul`) there is a dimension mismatch during a multiplication (`Mul`).

My guess is that, for your implementation, you need twice as many cells for the decoder LSTM as for the encoder LSTM, due to the fact that you are using a bidirectional encoder. If you have a bidirectional encoder with a LSTM with 256 cells, then the result will have 512 units (as you concatenate the outputs of the forward and backward LSTM). Currently the decoder seems to expect an input of 256 cells.

Comment: Do you mean to do like this
tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(2 * rnn_size)

Comment: tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(2 * rnn_size) solved the issue.